# How to use 'partitioning_func' in TimeScale DB

Tags: database, postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

From the documentation, I see that we can define a custom space partitioning function using `partitioning_func`. However, I don't find any hands-on example on how I can define the partitioning function and what should it return.

What I read is, by default it uses an INT32_MAX (key range in the hash table), for example, if we give `number_partitions=2` then numeric values < INT32_MAX/2 will fall into the first partition and remaining values will fall into the second partition.

In my case, let's say I have very few different values in the space partitioning column, then based on the default hashing function it is evident that all the values fall into the first partition. However, I want each different value to be in a different partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with one solution, if I have 2 different values in the space partitioning column, I want to put each value in a separate partition (that means I have 2 partitions).

As I mentioned in my questions timescale seems to use `INT32_MAX` in c language. Where `INT32_MAX` value is `2147483647` so I am dividing this by two to direct timescale to use 2 different partitions based on my space partition value (1 or 2).

The below code worked for me. I am using Postgres 12 with TimeScale 2.3.1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION two_partition_fun(i anyelement) RETURNS integer AS \$\$
        BEGIN
                RETURN 1073741821 + i;
        END;
\$\$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

I am not confident if this is a good approach, let me know if you got better approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple dimensions to a TimescaleDB Hypertable using `add_dimension`.

The main purpose of space partitioning is to enable parallelization across multiple data nodes (in the case of distributed hypertables) or across multiple disks within the same time interval.

There are some caveats including:

- The hypertable needs to be empty
- It may be appropriate for distributed hypertables, but for single node hypertables then the use case / need for `add_dimension` is relatively limited
- You should consider adding more than one additional dimension to be experimental and not use multiple additional dimensions in production.

There's much more detail around usage in the docs but this may be what you were looking for.

*Disclosure: I work for Timescale*

Answer (score 0):

I belive this might work:

If you want let's say 100 Tenant/partition and use smallint to count them from 0 to 99. Because 2147483647/100 = 21474836, the function would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SinglePartition(tenant anyelement) RETURNS 
integer AS 
$$
BEGIN
 RETURN tenant::smallint * 21474836 + 1;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```